# Dynamic Php Header cache Not working

Tags: php, caching

In My prepend file, i aded below code

```
$offset = 3600 * 24;
$expire = "Expires: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $offset) . " GMT";
Header($expire);
```

Now when I hit any URL, the header are

```
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding →gzip
Content-Length →7026
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Fri, 22 Jul 2016 08:26:22 GMT
Expires →Sat, 23 Jul 2016 08:26:22 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Server →Apache/2.4.18 (Fedora) PHP/5.6.23
Vary →Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.6.23
```

So I am expecting URL to be cached but next time when I am hitting the same URL again, all MySQL queries are executing again, which means caching is not set.

Please suggest.